# how to import data to html list with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, telegram

I need to import data in an python variable to html list this is part of my html and you can run it ..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Panel</title>
</head>
<style>
    
@import url('https://v1.fontapi.ir/css/Vazir');
body,html,.container{margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;font-family: "vazir",tahoma;}


.container {  
    font-family: "vazir";
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.7fr 0.9fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "addbot botstatus"
      "sendmsg blockuser";
      border-radius: 23px;
      background: #e0e0e0;
      box-shadow:  29px 29px 58px #bebebe,
                   -29px -29px 58px #ffffff;
      
  }
  
  .addbot { 
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    font-family: 'vazir';
    grid-area: addbot;
    border-radius: 23px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow:  29px 29px 58px #bebebe,
             -29px -29px 58px #ffffff;
    margin: 23px;
    
}

.addbot:hover{transform: scale(1);}.sendmsg:hover{transform: scale(1);}

  .botstatus { grid-area: botstatus; 
    border-radius: 23px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow:  29px 29px 58px #bebebe,
             -29px -29px 58px #ffffff;
             margin: 23px;
}
  
  .sendmsg { grid-area: sendmsg; 
    border-radius: 23px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow:  29px 29px 58px #bebebe,
             -29px -29px 58px #ffffff;

             margin: 23px;
}
  
  .blockuser { grid-area: blockuser; margin: 23px;
    border-radius: 23px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow:  29px 29px 58px #bebebe,
             -29px -29px 58px #ffffff;}
    .blockuser:hover{transform: scale(1);}
    .botstatus{transform: scale(1);}

input{
    padding: 5px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border-width: 3px;
     border-color: #CCCCCC;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     color: #000000;
     border-style: solid;
     border-radius: 0px;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(66,66,66,.75);
     text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(66,66,66,.75);
}
input:focus{
    border: none;
}
.addform{
text-align: center;
}
.delbot{text-align: center;}

.addbot {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
    gap: 0px 0px; 
    grid-template-areas: 
      "addbot delbot"; 
  }
  .addform { grid-area: addbot; }
  .delbot { grid-area: delbot; }
  .botstatus {text-align: center;color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  
  }
  
  .green{color: rgb(97, 209, 97);
    font-weight: bold;
}
  .lists{text-align: justify; }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="addbot">
            <div class="addform">
            <h1>اضافه کردن ربات جدید</h1>
            <form action="/login" method="GET">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="nm" name="nm"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="token" class="am" name="am"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </div>
            <div class="delbot">
                <h1>حذف ربات</h1>
            <form action="/login" method="GET">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="nmd" name="nmd"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="token" class="amd" name="amd"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="botstatus">
            <h1>وضعیت ربات ها</h1>
            <span class="lists">
            {{ botstatus }}
        </div>
    </span>
        <div class="sendmsg"></div>
        <div class="blockuser"></div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in right-up box i need to put os.listdir() and i need to when i add new item to directory when i refresh page list updates and show new item in list.
this is my python code:

```
from flask import *
import Botregistry
```

> this is an external library i've created and uses for create simple data base
> (i gonna say it in buttom of page) for read bot names with Botregistry.listbots()
> and add them with Botregistry.addbot(botname , bottoken)

```
 @app.route('/' )
 def home(): 
    botss=Botregistry.listbots()
```

> botss = Botregistry.listbots() =['bot1' , 'bot2' , ...]

```
return render_template('home.html' , botstatus = botss )
```

> my problem here!! 1.how can i create an system to get them and put it in list 2.why when i import html element with flask in {{ example element }} flask I see this :/  :

botregistry file :

and my hole **init**.py:

```html
from flask import *
import Botregistry 


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/' )
def home(): 
    botss=Botregistry.listbots()
    
    
    return render_template('home.html' , botstatus = botss )

@app.route("/login" , methods = ['GET'])

def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      name = request.form['nm']
      token = request.form['am']
      Botregistry.addbot(name=name , token=token)
      return 'ADDED SUCCESS WITH NAME {name} AND TOKEN {token}'.format(name = name , token = token)
    else:
      name = request.args.get('nm')
      token = request.args.get('am')
      Botregistry.addbot(name=name , token=token)
      return 'ADDED SUCCESS WITH NAME {name} AND TOKEN {token}'.format(name = name , token = token)


app.run(port=80 , debug=True)
```

and in the end ... some one knows about an program / system or anything to manage my bots with out need to change they code or create handler in telegram?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand your question correctly by saying that you want to display a Python list in your html page? I think you can try to replace

```
<span class="lists">
{{ botstatus }}
```

by something like this (looping over each entry to add them to an html list using a jinja for loop):

```
<ul>
    {% for bot in botstatus %}
        <li>{{bot}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

That way, you should be able to get the string values out of your list object.